# IIS 7 make subfolder starting point

Tags: html, iis, redirect, iis-7, webserver

In IIS 7 I have a website folder let's call it **mysite** - within this mysite folder lies my actual **index html** file in a folder called **start**. I want IIS 7 to point to the index page when the server url was entered but when I change the physical folder to ...\wwwroot\mysite\start I then lose the contents of the mysite folder of course.

I then put mysite to be the root again and tried to change the default document to start/index.html but this breaks my relative links.

Is there an easy way in IIS 7 to get this fixed, before I start messing with my links?

Quick and dirty would be a page inside mysite that redirects to the start/index.html but I'm sure you can tell me a nicer way to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: why your index page isn't in your top folder ?

Comment: I didn't come up with this folder structure :-) I think I will just copy the html page to the top folder and edit the links for now.

Comment: @BrOSs : I had to go with the dirty fix I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Sad to heard.. did you already fix it?

Comment: Why not use the Rewrite module (may have to install separately, possibly via Web Platform Installer) to send the user to that particular URL if they come in at the base URL?